Using bearer token to authorize KeyCloak service
I am trying to authorize to my KeyCloak service with correct bearer token which I receive from API, just to get into my keycloak resources but I receive logging page as result when I try to send this token as Bearer in Authorization tab from Postman. Does any settings on KeyCloak administration could prevent that? I tried to sent this token attached to url but without positive result.
Maybe there is possibility to achieve that with some javascript if possible to avoid CORS policy?
